# Is there any way to get the number of threads from the user's cpu in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the number of user threads in javascript. Not the number of cores.
Example: Intel® Xeon® Gold 6132 Processor
Cores: 14
Threads: 28

Comment: There is no standard JavaScript API to get that kind of information. This in particular is not relevant to normal JavaScript (single-threaded) programming.

Comment: In what environment is your javascript running, node.js?

Comment: @Pointy Maybe it's the number of user threads on the box, using Javascript? I would think Node could do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running JavaScript on NodeJS, then `os` module is what you are looking

```
const os = require('os');
console.log('Number of cores = ' + os.cpus.length);
console.log('Core name = ' + os.cpus[index].model);
```

You can find more details for methods in os module here: [OS Module](https://nodejs.org/api/os.html)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will try it.

Answer (score 0):

In NodeJS,

```
const os = require('os');
const availableCPUs = os.cpus().length;
console.log(availableCPUs);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i will try it.